# Use Image Styles with remote images?

Tags: 7, media

I have a set of images on a separate host, images are available by a URL. I would like to render one of these using Drupal's image styles, but I note that [theme_image_style](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) says it won't work with remote images.

Is this possible some other way?

I would like it to use Drupal's caching (so it doesn't fetch the original image every time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a module for that.

[Imagecache external](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_external)